# R: plot ignores ylab with formula

Tags: r, plot

Using R language and `plot()` with a *formula* ignores the `ylab` parameter selectively (other parameters such as xlab, col etc. do work). In the following example, xlab becomes "new x" (correct) but ylab stays "y" (i.e. the name of the variable used in the formula) instead of "new y".

The use case is a quite bulky variable name resulting from a data.frame column used in a loop or vectorized structure).

```
x <- 1:5
y <- (1:5) * 2
plot(x, y)                                # works
plot(x, y, xlab="new x", ylab="new y")    # works
plot(~ x + y)                             # works
plot(~ x + y, col="red", pch=3, xlab="new x", ylab="new y") # selectively ylab does not work
```

Is there a reason for that, or a workaround (other/easier than avoiding the formula method or finding `xlim` and `ylim` manually, creating an empty plot with the correct `xlab` and `ylab` labels, and then use `add=T` to add the real data by formula plot?

`plot()` seems to be `base::plot()`, but both ways with *base* or *graphics* result in the same plot ignoring `ylab`.

```
environment(plot)  # <environment: namespace:base>
base::plot(~ x + y, col="red", pch=3, xlab="new x", ylab="new y")
graphics::plot(~ x + y, col="red", pch=3, xlab="new x", ylab="new y")
```

As far as I can guess, `plot` calls `plot.formula`, but I cannot see the source code to find a better solution (the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72571755/3414968) in a great answer for another problem resulting in the `add=T` suggestion):

```
base::plot.formula
# Error: object 'plot.formula' not found

graphics::plot.formula
# Error: 'plot.formula' is not an exported object from 'namespace:graphics'
```

Comment: You need three colons: `graphics:::plot.formula`

Comment: `plot(~ x + y)` is not the equivalent of `plot(x, y)`. It is `plot(y ~ x)` and in this way also `ylab` works.

Comment: @GKi Great! Actually this form of the formula was used because I wanted to use the same formula for cor.test() (requiring this form of the formula) and plot() for brevity and to minimize potential typing errors during develoopment. Is there a difference between ~x+y and y~x other than that ylab works or not?

Comment: @Edward Thanks for the hint! Now I see the code. Trying to figure out why it would ignore my passed ylab, since it actually has an explicit ylab parameter (with default value - not sure why I cannot override it? Grateful for further hints.

Comment: See `?plot.formula`: *For the ‘plot’ method the formula can be of the form ‘~ z + y + z’: the variables specified on the right-hand side are collected into a data frame, subsetted if specified, and displayed by ‘plot.data.frame’.* And there the names are taken from the formula.

Comment: If you look at the code, lines 35-85 are not called because `response` is FALSE. So the function then calls plot.data.frame, which takes the `ylab` from the second column of the formula you gave, in this case "y". So, your `ylab` argument is silently ignored.